# Как проще всего разметить найденные стеммером ключевые слова в тексте? Через список?

Tags: python, list, keyword

Есть текст- набор предложений. Его слова приводятся к базовой форме стеммером.

На входе: Строка. Обычно это порядка 20 kB текста. Статья из предложений русского текста. Кодировка (utf8) и  прочие подобные параметры- можно сделать любыми, вряд ли это принципиально .

Пример «У Олега появился друг Олег»

После работы стеммера получится некий объект, который пока непонятно в чем хранить. Например , это может быть список или кортеж: [‘У’ , ‘Олег’, ‘появляться’,’ Олег’]   *обрабатывая данный список мы находим самое частотное слово*

На выходе: нужно получить строку (исходного текста)в которой ключевые слова обернуты html тегами, например тегами жирного текста :
 `«У <b>Олега</b> появился друг <b>Олег</b>»`

Как это лучше сделать? Единственное  что приходит в голову- исходные слова вставить в список, затем после стеммера зная номер слова в списке- его уже обернуть тегами. И потом от списка вернуться к обычному тексту.

Может есть более простой вариант какой?

Answer (score 1):

Так как стеммер нацелен на поиск основы слова, а основа слова это неизменяемая часть слова, то на мой взгляд неплохим подходом будет выделение текста с помощью регулярного выражения. Регулярка для поиска будет выглядеть как-то так `[^\s]*Олег[^\s]*`. Чтобы обернуть совпадающие выражения в теги, надо будет использовать группы.

Comment: "Так как стеммер нацелен на поиск основы слова, а основа слова это неизменяемая часть слова,"

- наверное, я использовал слово "стеммер" некорректно, видимо, вы правы- стеммер это то что отсекает суффиксы- окончания.
У меня же видимо , лемматизатор (?) - то что еще и достаточно умное чтобы приводить слово к базовой форме. Например , "бывал"->"быть" тут явно не простое отсечение .

Но я использую mystem Яндекса, они сами свой продукт почему то называют стеммером..

Comment: тогда думаю, что тот вариант который Вы предложили в тексте вопроса подойдет. Не знаю, по какому принципу работает mystem, но я бы еще сделал предварительный анализ текста, убрав из него стоп-слова ( предлоги, союзы, цифры, и.т.д)

Comment: @ Nexus
Да,  при поиске самого частотного - и стоп слова убираю и вообще все что до 3 символов в длину - выбрасывается.